# How to find out the CPU bottleneck of web page

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Affiliate web sites embed our site into a `<iframe />`. I found that the **CPU consumption** keeps quite high even i don't do anything to the web page.

I try to figure it out what is going on behind the scenes. I suspect some javascript timer is the culprit. Do you know any tool or methodology helping on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Modern webbrowsers include profilers. For example, with Google Chrome:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to show the developer tools
2. Select the `Profiles` tab.
3. Click on the `Start Profiling` button in the bottom left (the red circle)
4. Navigate to the problematic webpage, and leave it for a couple of seconds
5. Click the `Stop Profiling Button` and examine the results by clicking `Profile 1` on the left